# How to count how many items equals Todays Day one by one?

Tags: java, android, notificationmanager

I am using this to test if  a date is equal to today's date as in day. My items are parsed from HTML     one

```
while(postIt.hasNext)
```

and it keeps going until there are not anymore left.

```
 if(itemDate.contains(todaysDay)){ 
     System.out.println(i);
     nm = (NotificationManager) this.
             getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     CharSequence from = "App";
     CharSequence message = nameItem3 + "Today is the day!";
     PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
             this, 0, new Intent(this, HtmlparserExample.class), 0);
     Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, 
             nameOfItem + "Today is the day!!", System.currentTimeMillis());
     notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, from, message, contentIntent);
     nm.notify(1, notif);
  }
```

What i want to do is test if there are more than one item that equals todays date.
If so i want to do something if it is.

How would i go about tracking how many items are todays Day?

What i want to happen is when the items are retreived they are tested if more than 1 item equals today's day, it shows a different notification.

Whats happening now is that it is displaying a notification for each item that has the same date as todays day, one after the other.

Or something else that would work is i could i show a notification for each one? How could i do that too?

Vs. it overriding each one and showing a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your itemDate instances which satisfy your test in an array, and based on the contents of the array, notify the user outside the while loop.

**EDIT**

```
ArrayList<ItemDate> itemDates = new ArrayList<ItemDate>();
while(postIt.hasNext){
    /* Do stuff */
    if(itemDate.contains(todaysDay)){
        itemDates.add(itemDate);
        /* Do stuff, not notifying */
    }
}

/* Notify using instances in itemDates */
```

Comment: So why did you add itemDates.add()?

Comment: and how could i get the position at which each item is in the arraylist so i can show the name if the item in the notification?